# Asymptotic behavior of the quadratic recurrence $x_n=x_{n-1}^2+c$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, complex-dynamics

Let $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$. I am looking for a sequence $\{y_n\}$ that asymptotically (and if possible tightly) upper bounds the recurrence
$$x_n=x^2_{n-1}+c.$$
I would to like to write $y_n$ as a function of $n$, $x_0$, and $c$.

Comment: Do you have a sufficient knowledge of this well studied sequence, for example the way to work with conjugates like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3626163) ? Could you say which interest could have the study of a sequence bounding this one ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Not at all. My only knowledge is a few questions on MSE here and there. I asked a similar question before https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136248/bounding-the-nth-term-of-a-sequence-given-a-recursive-non-linear-bound when $x_n=ax_{n-1}+bx_{n-1}^2$. But it turns out this was not the case I am interested in.

Comment: I can add that I am interested in the case when $c << 1$. But if there are well known cases then this would be a plus.

Comment: @JeanMarie Since this sequence is well studied, do you have references for it?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_of_real_numbers/r_iterations#Real_quadratic_map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is about the asymptotic behavior of $\,x_n = x_{n-1}^2+c\,$ given **any**
$\,x_0\ge0\,$ and $\,c\ge0.\,$ A simple example is [OEIS sequence A003095](https://oeis.org/A003095) where $\,x_0=0,\;c=1.\,$ The **general** answer depends on
$$ f_c(x) := \frac1{2x} \!-\! \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(c) x^{2n+1} 
= \frac1{2x}\\ - (c)x - (2c\!+\!c^2) x^3 - (4c^2\!+\!2c^3)x^5 -
(16c \!+\! 12c^2 \!+\! 12c^3 \!+\! 5c^4)x^7 - \dots$$
where $\,a_n(1)\,$ is [OEIS sequence A088674](https://oeis.org/A088674).
This function satisfies the equations
$$ f_c(x)^2 + c = f_c(2x^2) \quad\text{ and }\quad
f_c(x) = \sqrt{f_c(2x^2)-c}. $$ The second equation iterated determines
the coefficients $\,a_n(c)\,$ as polynomials in $\,c.\,$ Thus,
$$ x_n \simeq y_n := f_c\big(d^{-2^n}/2\big) \;\; \text{ where }\;\;
 d := \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^{(2^{-n})}
 $$ is the asymptotic expansion
of $\,x_n.\,$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, the case $x_0=0$ is not of much interest to me. Are there other such examples with $x_0>0$?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know of any reference for the detailed study of the matter? In particular, a reference that computes all constants that prove $x_n\in \Theta(y_n)$, which is what I understand from the answer.

Comment: @UserA A general reference for this is Chapter 8 of de Bruijn's *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis*.